# Перевод Unicode в ANSI

Tags: c#, delphi, unicode, ansi

На Делфи реализована работа с сторонней dll.В функцию этой dll передается в том числе и массив AnsiChar (именно AnsiChar):

```
type
    TChaineCpp = array [0..5] of AnsiChar;
var
    tmp_key: TChaineCpp;    
    name: string;
...
///Подготовка key
  FillChar(tmp_key, SizeOf(tmp_key), ' ');
  for i := 1 to Length(name) do
  begin
    tmp_key[i - 1] := AnsiChar(name[i]);
  end;
...
//передача key в функцию
GET_CALCULATION(vs1, vs2, input, tmp_key, vz1, vz2, vGS_OUTPUT);
```

Идет переписывание на C#. При этом вызываемая из dll функция говорит о том, что некорректное значение параметра key. При этом он совершенно верный. Подобная проблема решалась в Делфи приведением к AnsiChar (см. код выше). Вот часть реализации на C#:

```cs
[DllImport("rekplus.dll", EntryPoint = "GET_CALCULATION@28", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void GET_CALCULATION(int s1, int s2, double[] GS_INPUT, char[] key, int z1, int z2, double[] GS_OUTPUT);

...
char[] key = new char[6] { 'R', 'E', 'C', '+', '5', '3' };
GET_CALCULATION(vs1, vs2, GS_INPUT, key, vz1, vz2, GS_OUTPUT);
```

Т.е., на сколько сейчас понимаю, проблема именно в несоответствии Unicod'а (из C#) и AnsiChar. Пытался конвертировать так:

```cs
string name = "REC+53";
char[] key = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(name)).ToCharArray();
```

Есть ли другой способ конвертации? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: потеряли [`Encoding.Convert(...)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.convert?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char[]` вам не походит, потому что это всегда юникод (UTF-16). Используйте `byte[]`.

```cs
public static extern void GET_CALCULATION(int s1, int s2, double[] GS_INPUT, byte[] key, int z1, int z2, double[] GS_OUTPUT);
```

Затем просто

```cs
byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);
```